# Merge two CSV files with no headers in Powershell

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I have two CSV files and neither have headers. Both CSV files have the same amount of lines in them. Here's an example:

csv1.csv:
1,2
3,4
5,6

csv2.csv:
a,b
c,d
e,f

I would like the output to look like this:
1,2,a,b
3,4,c,d
5,6,e,f

I don't want to add headers or anything like that. I just want to basically take columns 1 and 2 from csv2.csv and paste them to columns 3 and 4 of csv1.csv, or just export to a combined csv.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I just notice my formatting changed. The csv1 and csv2 lines should only be two columns wide so 1,2 being on line one, 3,4 being on line two. Same for csv2. The combined output would be 4 columns wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough, just ignore the fact that they're CSV files, for a For loop based on line count, and join each line with a comma.

```
$CSV1 = Get-Content C:\Path\To\File1.csv
$CSV2 = Get-Content C:\Path\To\File2.csv
For($i=0;$i -lt $csv1.count;$i++){
    $CSV1[$i],$CSV2[$i] -join ','|Out-File C:\Path\to\NewFile.CSV
}
```

That should output a file as desired:
1,2,a,b
3,4,c,d
5,6,e,f

Comment: Thank you very much! I was so hung up on it being a csv and using import-csv to manipulate! The only thing I had to add is a '-append' to the out-file.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to make this extremely simply and add the second csv to the end of the first you could do something like this

```
$csv1 = Get-Content C:\path\to\first.csv
$csv2 = Get-Content C:\path\to\second.csv

"$csv1,$csv2" | Add-Content C:\path\to\third.csv
```

The output woud look something like

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Not quite what I'm going for though. This gives me a one line file. I need the file to be 4 lines deep.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this - I've made it only include rows which are present in both files, but you might have different requirements.

```
$lines1 = Get-Content "File1.csv"
$lines2 = Get-Content "File2.csv"
$destination = "Combined.csv"

# Make sure the destination file doesn't already exist
Remove-Item $destination

$length = [Math]::Min($lines1.Length, $lines2.Length)
for ($index = 0; $index -lt $length; $index++)
{
    # Append rows
    Add-Content $destination ($lines1[$index] + ", " + $lines2[$index])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a powershell solution but a little known fact is you can merge files in DOS like this:

`COPY File.CSV + File2.CSV OutputFile.CSV`